# VBA Excel wildcard string search, copy and paste to new cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for help in trying to do the following.

I have large amount of data in Excel (100K+ rows) which have many columns, in one of the columns (lets just say col A) there is a string of data in each cell that lists file path info indicating a java installation. I need to search within that string to find common characters that start and end the same but will have different data in-between, so wildcard would be needed to identify.  After identifying the data in the string search for each cell in the specified column (col A) I need to copy and paste the data identified to a different column located just right of the data (col B) on same worksheet for each row.  So would look something like this:

> **Example**
>
> **COLUMN A** ***(original data string)***
>   C:\app\Java\jre7\bin\...
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\...
>   C:\app\JAVA\jdk1.7.0._21\jre\bin\...
>   C:\JAVA\JDK-1_5_0_16_i586\jre\bin\...
>
> **COLUMN B** ***(copy & paste to here)***
>   jre7
>   jre6
>   jdk1.7.0._21
>   JDK-1_5_0_16_i586

Would need wildcard search to pick up anything specific between the \ & \ that starts with letter ***j*** and would be followed by two letters which could be ***re*** or ***dk*** but would have to allow for character or number to follow this in any length.  Would be something like `\j??*#*\` for the search always starting with same first two characters, followed by two letters, then possibly another character or nothing at all before a version number, then can be no characters or many after the version number.

As you can see from examples I am trying to pick up the version info with version numbers in them and do not want to get dir info with ***jre*** or ***jdk*** only in them, since most of my data have these dir listed somewhere in the file path string.

Then copying this info and pasting into Col B as shown in example is what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is a manual process that would benefit greatly from automating.

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code. Take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/) or [Mid-Advanced Tutorials](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/codes-examples-macros-how-tos-most-useful-basics-advanced/) and my [personal favorite](http://analystcave.com/excel-vba-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a really quick way to do this using formulas. You could combine all of these into one formula if you wish, but I spread it into four simple formulas with the fourth giving you the answer.

Assuming the first string is in cell A1:

B1 = =SEARCH("java",A1)

C1 = =FIND("\",A1,E1)

D1 = =FIND("\",A1,F1+1)

E1 = =MID(A1,F1+1,G1-F1-1)

E1 will have your answer. Autofill down the columns and then copy>paste values in column E and delete columns B-D.